# How to setState of computed property using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

so I'm updating an old project of mine to use hooks wherever possible instead of state all the time. I'm basically refactoring the project and making it better based on what I've learnt since.

I came across this

```
handleChange(event){
   setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
}
```

I have created a `useState` hook for other values in the component but I don't know how I'd go about setting state for a computed property.

```
Password: <input className= "userNameBox" type="password" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} onKeyPress={this.enterPressed.bind(this)}></input>
```

Above is where I call the method incase that's relevant.

Could anyone tell me what I would change in this method in order for it to use hooks?

Comment: Could you show what your original state looks like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With hooks, you need to use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) with `prevState` because it doesn't merge with previous state like with [`this.setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) equivalent.

See [State Updates Are Merged](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged).

```
const Component = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({ password: "" });
  const onChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    setValue((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
  };
  return <input name="password" value={value.password} onChange={onChange} />;
};
```

Comment: When I replace my handleChange function with yours I lost the ability to type in the text boxes. Do I need to include the event paramater somewhere?

Comment: Don't just copy-paste solutions, its a generic answer - like a generic question you asked, you should show how exactly you use it and your component's structure, better to ask a new question with relevant context.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need import useState method from React as follows.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
```

After that, use useState method with initial value.

```
const [state, setState] = useState(null);
```

And finally, just update the handleChange method.

```
handleChange(event){
    setState(event.target.value);
}
```

Please examine [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) for details. You can also use [useEffect](https://tr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) method. It's better for when multiple states required