# How to setState of a computed property using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Link to original question: [How to setState of computed property using hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62406168/how-to-setstate-of-computed-property-using-hooks)

I'm basically trying to update an old project to use hooks and functional components where possible. I need to update the state of a computed property using hooks in the handleChange function. How would I do this?

I've removed the irrelevant code in the following snippet:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import AuthenticationService from '../service/AuthenticationService';

export const LoginComponent1 = () => {
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState('Neil');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
      this.setState(
        {
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        }
      );
    }

    const loginClicked = () => {
       ...
    }


    const enterPressed = (event) => {
        ...
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <div className="container">

                User Name: <input className= "userNameBox" type="text" placeholder="Neil" name="username" value={userName} onChange={handleChange} onKeyPress={enterPressed}></input>
                Password: <input className= "userNameBox" type="password" id="myInput" name="password" value={password} onChange={handleChange} onKeyPress={enterPressed}></input>
                <hr></hr>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default LoginComponent1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While declaring a state in functional component the second parameter you are passing is a method used to set the state. `this.setState` is available only in class components. [See here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

In your example for setting the state password, you need to call the method `setPassword` with value. 
Eg: `setPassword('this is my password')`

Answer (score 1):

`this.setState` exists only in class components, not functional ones.

For updating state with `useState` hooks, simply call the corresponding setter. In your example, call `setUserName` to update the username, `setPassword` to update the password and so on.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a generic handler like before you had at react based component with multiple state handlers you could create an object handler after your `useState` hooks and refactor your handleChange like:

```
const handler = {
  username: setUserName,
  password: setPassword
}

const handleChange = (event) => handler[event.target.name](event.target.value)
```